# Laravel: validate unique arrays on update

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, unique, updates

I know when I need to update value in database I can use unique rule like this `'name' => 'unique:phones,name,'.$request->phone_id,`
But how can I apply third argument to unique rule when I am validating arrays? I tried to do it like this `'phone_sku.*.sku' => 'unique:phones_skus,sku,phone_sku.*.id',` but it isn`t working.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Please explain what do you mean by "not working". Also post the code to where you are implementing the validation part

Comment: I believe you should create a separate rule for each unique attribute. For example: `unique:phones_skus,sku|unique:phones_skus,id`